# AS3 TextInput into TextField

Tags: message, textfield, textinput

I am creating a small chat application. I want to edit a message in a TextInput field and when the user hit's Enter on the Keyboard the message will be transferred from the TextInput over to the TextArea. How do I do this?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add an event listener to the keyboard events see here

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/KeyboardEvent.html#keyCode

Enter will have a specific keyboard code on the event you can right logic for eg;

```
addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handleKeyboard);

function handleKeyboard(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
// eg if (e.keycode == //the code for enter )
{
//your chat send message logic
}

//of course find the different keycodes easily by trace(e.keycode)
}
```